# Approximations to $\pi$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is there a way to efficiently solve the following problem besides brute-force calculation?

Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (say $n=100$).  Find the integers $p,q,r,s$ with $0\leq p,q,r,s\leq n$ such that
$$\pm\frac{p}{q}\pm\sqrt{\frac{r}{s}}$$
most closely approximates $\pi$.

Some cases can be handled by finding the continued fraction expansion of $(\pi-\frac{p}{q})^2$ for various $p,q$.  Playing with this method I found the approximation $4-\sqrt{\frac{14}{19}}$, which is really quite good, but may not be best for $n=20$.  Note that the solution will be unique (for a given $n$).

Comment: 3 + sqrt(1/50) isn't too shabby. Gerhard "That's Without Pencil And Paper" Paseman, 2020.01.28.

Comment: 4-sqrt(14/19) is more than an order of magnitude better (but not without pencil and paper!)

Comment: Such numbers have eventually periodic continued fractions. Maybe something can be done comparing periodic continued fractions to the continued fraction of $\pi$?

Comment: I guess the key to that approach would be to give an upper bound for $\max(p,q,r,s)$ in terms of the continued fraction, enabling a (hopefully) efficient search over periodic continued fraction approximations.

Comment: Below $100$, only one stands out: $71/28+\sqrt{29/79}$. Next best is $-47/46+\sqrt{52/3}$, far behind.

Comment: Nice!  How did you find this?

Comment: @BruceBlackadar: `gawk -v n=100 'function abs(x) {if(x>0) return x; else return -x;} function gcd(a,b,       x,y,t) {x=a; y=b; if (x<y) {t=x; x=y; y=t;} while (y>0) {t=x%y; x=y; y=t;} return (x);} BEGIN {tol=1/n^2; pi=3.141592653589793238462643383276; for(a=-n; a<=n; a++) for(b=1; b<=n; b++) if(gcd(abs(a),b)==1) {r=pi-a/b; rr=r*r; for(d=1; d<=n; d++) {c=int(d*rr+0.5); if(c<=n && gcd(c,d)==1) {pp=a/b+sqrt(c/d); if(abs(pi-pp)<tol) print tol/abs(pi-pp), a "/" b "+sqrt(" c "/" d ")"; pp=a/b-sqrt(c/d); if(abs(pi-pp)<tol) print tol/abs(pi-pp), a "/" b "-sqrt(" c "/" d ")";}}}}' | sort -n -k1 | tail`

Comment: @BruceBlackadar: beware gawk has only about 15 digits of precision, so n=1000 is almost as far as you can go with this hack.

Comment: @BruceBlackadar: I just noticed that the comment syntax deleted the STAR symbol ("*"), so that above rr=rr should be rr=r STAR r and drr should be d STAR rr. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: OK, so essentially brute force.  I was hoping for a procedure similar to the continued fraction method of finding best rational approximations.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch: Use backticks to surround code: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Some versions of gawk have -M for multiprecision. Gerhard "So Check Your Gawk Version" Paseman, 2020.01.30.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: yes indeed. And the roots and floats can easily be avoided allow to work with integers only.

Answer (score 6):

This is not exactly an answer to the stated question, but it's too long for a comment. Rather than the form given in the question, one could represent a number in the form $\frac{a + b \sqrt{d}}{c}$, where $d$ is a squarefree positive integer,
and this form lends itself to finding good approximations to $\pi$ using lattice reduction.

Fix a bound $n$. For each squarefree $d$ with $1 \leq d \leq n$,
choose a constant $X \approx n^{2} \sqrt{d}$ and create the lattice in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ spanned by
$$ v_{1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ X \pi \end{bmatrix}, v_{2} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -X \end{bmatrix}, v_{3} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -X \sqrt{d} \end{bmatrix}. $$

A short vector in this lattice with respect to the $\ell_{2}$ norm is a linear combination $a v_{1} + bv_{2} + cv_{3}$ and because the fourth coordinate of these vectors are so large, this forces $\frac{a+b \sqrt{d}}{c}$ to be a close approximation to $\pi$.

Finding the shortest vector in a lattice is a hard problem, even in small dimensional lattices. However, one can get within a constant multiple of the true minimum using the LLL-algorithm. With this, the above algorithm would run in time $O(n \log^{3} n)$ and find "some good solutions", but isn't guaranteed to find the optimal representation (even in this modified form).

I ran this with $n = 10^{6}$ and $X = n^{2} \sqrt{d} \log(n)$ and obtained (after about a minute and a half)
$$
\pi \approx \frac{-327031 + 7075 \sqrt{224270}}{962406}.
$$
The approximation differs from the truth by about $8 \cdot 10^{-22}$.

Comment: An approximation using $22$ digits, and good to $10^{-22}$. About what one might expect, no?

Comment: To answer Gerry Myerson's question - yes, this is about as good (or even a little worse) an approximation as one would expect. Perhaps I wasn't clear above - for a fixed $d$ the lattice reduction is polynomial time and takes about $O(\log^{3} n)$, and so looping over all $d$, the runtime is something like $O(n \log^{A} n)$ for some $A$ depending on how quick the arithmetic is.

Comment: A brute force search to find $\pi \approx (a+\sqrt{b})/c$ can be done with a loop of the form `for(a=-n; a<=n; a++) for(c=max(1,int((a-sqrt(n))/pi)); c<=min(n,(a+sqrt(n))/pi); c++) {b=...}` and therefore $O(n^{3/2}\log^A)$ operations for some small $A$ that I'm not sure about. Not too much worse than the clever but non-optimal scheme suggested here. **However** notice that I have $\sqrt{b}$ here rather, than the $b\sqrt{d}$ of this answer.

Comment: In under 3 minutes, for $n=10^6$, the best, unexciting approximation $\pi\approx (108062-\sqrt{99097})/34297$ is found, good to about $4 \cdot 10^{-16}$.